# MySQL and PHP: Searching for rows through a field in an undefined number of joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

There is an example table, 'main_table' with the fields 'ID', 'some_data'.

There is an aggregate table, 'agg' with the fields 'id', 'main_table_id', 'joinee_id'.

And then there is the final table, 'joinee', with the fields 'id', 'email'.

The tables 'main_table' and 'joinee' are in a many:many relationship, through 'agg'.

I would like to be able to search all the 'main_table' entries by 'email' from 'joinee', without doing a left join and then group by 'main_table'.'id'.
The final result needs to list all the 'main_table' entries, once per entry. Imagine it like this - I would like 'main_table' to get a temporary field "participants" which would contain all the 'emails' - I would then perform a LIKE match on this field in the same query that does this, in order to find the 'main_table' entries that have anything to do with the email I entered.

Is this possible?

Mind you, this is only a fragment of a much larger query. 'main_table' is already joined with 5 other tables, and their fields are already used as filters. Thing is, I know there can be only one joined table in each of those cases - with 'joinee', the number of connected entries varies.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining row results into single cells is something the relational model does not support, and most DBMSes are exceptionally bad at it. If you were to go down that road, you'd need to pull a considerable amount of hacking, like using user-defined functions or nonstandard syntax features to combine the values.

But if I understand you correctly, your problem is that you need to find entries in the main table that have desirable entries in their related email rows, and the problem is that there's a many-to-many relation.

How about this:

1. Write a query that finds the `email`s you're interested in and `inner join` that on the `agg` table. This will give you the related `main_table_id`s. Use `distinct` or `group by` to remove doubles.
2. Use the query from 1 as a subquery, and plug it into the query as you have it now, using something like `WHERE main_table.id IN (/* subquery */)`, or, alternatively, `inner join` your existing query on the subquery from step 1. Which of these you use depends on the circumstances; traditionally, subqueries are slower than joins (all else being equal), but it may be the other way around, depending on your structure and actual data. On some older DMBSes, buffering the subquery result in a temporary table can prove beneficial.

Comment: Thank you for this response, I will test this and report back with my findings!

Comment: While I ended up rewriting the query completely, this was the proper answer to handling the then-current query. Thank you!